# Can't get rid of spaces in input

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to code a states and capitals quiz and I almost have it complete however when I try to input any of the capitals where I have to put in 2 words (i.e. Little Rock or Oklahoma City) it has it as 2 separate inputs and for the life of me I can't get it to count it as one.

Here's my code thus far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    
    ArrayList<String> States = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Object> Capitals = new ArrayList<>(States);
    
    
    String capitals [][] = {
        {"Alabama", "Montgomery"},
        {"Alaska", "Juneau"},
        {"Arizona", "Phoenix"},
        {"Arkansas", "LittleRock"},
        {"California", "Sacramento"},
        {"Colorado", "Denver"},
        {"Connecticut", "Hartford"},
        {"Delaware", "Dover"},
        {"Florida", "Tallahasse"},
        {"Georgia", "Atlanta"},
        {"Hawaii", "Honolulu"},
        {"Idaho", "Boise"},
        {"Illinois", "Springfield"},
        {"Indiana", "Indianapolis"},
        {"Iowa", "DesMoines"},
        {"Kansas", "Topeka"},
        {"Kentucky", "Frankfort"},
        {"Louisiana", "BatonRouge"},
        {"Maine", "Augusta"},
        {"Maryland", "Annapolis"},
        {"Massachusettes", "Boston"},
        {"Michigan", "Lansing"},
        {"Minnesota", "Saint Paul"},
        {"Mississippi", "Jackson"},
        {"Missouri", "JeffersonCity"},
        {"Montana", "Helena"},
        {"Nebraska", "Lincoln"},
        {"Nevada", "CarsonCity"},
        {"New Hampshire", "Concord"},
        {"New Jersey", "Trenton"},
        {"New York", "Albany"},
        {"New Mexico", "SantaFe"},
        {"North Carolina", "Raleigh"},
        {"North Dakota", "Bismark"},
        {"Ohio", "Columbus"},
        {"Oklahoma", "OklahomaCity"},
        {"Oregon", "Salem"},
        {"Pennslyvania", "Harrisburg"},
        {"Rhode Island", "Providence"},
        {"South Carolina", "Columbia"},
        {"South Dakota", "Pierre"},
        {"Tennessee", "Nashville"},
        {"Texas", "Austin"},
        {"Utah", "Salt Lake City"},
        {"Vermont", "Montpelier"},
        {"Virginia", "Richmond"},
        {"Washington", "Olympia"},
        {"West Virginia", "Charleston"},
        {"Wisconsin", "Madison"},
        {"Wyoming", "Cheyenne"}
    };
    
    
    for(int i = 0; i<=49; i++){
        States.add(capitals[i][0]);
        Capitals.add(capitals[i][1]);
    }
    
    
    for(int i = 0; i<49; i++){
        String guess;
        int index = (int)((Math.random())*(49 - i));
        System.out.println("What is the capital of: " + States.get(index));
        States.remove(index);
        
        guess = input.next();
        
        if(Capitals.get(index).equals(guess)){
            System.out.println("Correct");
            Capitals.remove(index);
        }else{ System.out.println("Incorrect");
            Capitals.remove(index);
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that `input` is a scanner -- you're telling it to read from stdin to the next delimiter, which includes whitespace.  You could either change the delimiter pattern, or maybe use `nextLine()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on what @Gus is saying here
" You could either change the delimiter pattern, or maybe use nextLine()",

Reading single tokens may be your downfall. "I like pie" is read separated as "I" "like" "pie" with **line.next()** but together as "I like pie" with **line.nextLine()**

**EDIT FOR MORE DETAIL**
To bring an example line in:

```
for(int i = 0; i<=49; i++)    // {"Utah", "Salt Lake City"},
{
    States.add(capitals[i][0]); // add Utah
    Capitals.add(capitals[i][1]); // add Salt
}
```

In this index, **capitals[44][]**, the size is set to 4 because of every single word read.